# I would like to determine the setup language from InstallScript

Tags: installation, installshield, setup-project, installscript, installshield-2015

I am using InstallShield as a install solution, and I would like to determine what user selected as setup language from InstallScript. Is there any properties or something I could use to determine this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the [`SELECTED_LANGUAGE` variable](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/installshield22helplib.htm#StartTopic=Subsystems/installshield22langref/helplibrary/LangrefSELECTEDLANGUAGE.htm) to identify the display language of the installation.